# What plant is this? Green/reed succulent like leaves

Tags: identification, succulents, outdoor

[image]

I've searched but I can't find what plant is it.

Comment: Possibly some kind of Mesemb like a Faucaria.  Just a couple guesses. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Marlothistella stenophylla](http://www.llifle.com/Encyclopedia/SUCCULENTS/Family/Aizoaceae/18211/Marlothistella_stenophylla) Also called Mesembryanthemum stenophyllum or
Ruschia stenophylla  It is not very common.  It should at some point grow a caudex.  A caudex of a plant is a stem, but the term is also used to mean a rootstock and particularly a basal stem structure from which new growth arises.   You might already be able to feel one forming at the base.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks very much like what Californians call "iceplant". Wikipedia says that its real name is now Carpobrotus edulis, that its *former* name was "Mesembryanthemum edule", and that it is native to the South of Africa.

Wikipedia is also where I found this picture of it:

[image: iceplant]
(photo by Uzoma Ozurumba)

I should note this picture makes the plant look much more beautiful than it appears when it grows naturalized in California.

Your plant looks a little small yet for flowers; has it ever flowered? Carpobrotus edulis does:
[image]
(photo by "Anachronist", also courtesy of Wikipedia)

If your plant isn't this exact species, I suspect it is a close relative.